# Chrome extension content script CSS not injecting

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to inject a CSS file into the paypal home page, but for some reason it wont work. Below is my manifest file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Paypal Addon",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "example",
    "permissions": ["https://www.paypal.com/*"], 
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": false
},
    "content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["https://www.paypal.com/*"],
"css": ["style-fix.css"],
"js": ["jquery-2.1.0.min.js", "contentScript.js"]

}]
}
```

And below is the CSS file style-fix.css:

```
body {
color: red !important;
}
```

Does anybody know why the CSS isnt being applied? thanks

Comment: What browser console tells?

Comment: I get nothing in the console!

Comment: The only text that CSS changes is the `© 1999 - 2014 PayPal` in the footer. Try using a better CSS rule that will actually change more of the page.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS is working but not visible. Try this instead:

```
* {
    color: red;
}
```

All of the text in the document is styled with a higher priority except the copyright.